# Llamar a una propiedad desde una variable (JavaScript || TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, typescript

Un Saludo a todos.
Estoy trabajando en un proyecto y quisiera saber como desde una varible podria llamar a un elemento de mi objeto.

**EJEMPLO:**
Tengo un Objeto user

```
type test ={
    Name?:string;
    lastName?:string;
}

let user:test = {
    Name: "Lorem",
    lastName: "Ipsum"
};
```

desde una funcion me gustaria seleccionar a name o a lastname:

```
function getValue(value: string) {
    return user.<value> //nombre del elemto  
}

getValue("Name");
```

y que:

```
getValue("Name");
```

sea lo mismo que:

```
user.Name
```

Comment: Cuando es un objeto puedes acceder de dos formas a sus propiedades en este caso seria `return user[value]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para acceder de manera dinámica a las propiedades dentro de los objetos en `javascript` y `typescript` deberías usar llaves `[]`, entonces deberías modificar tu función así:

```ts
interface Test {
    name?: string;
    lastName?: string;
}

let user: Test = {
    name: "Lorem",
    lastName: "Ipsum"
};

function getValue(value: string) {
    return user?.[value] || 'Error: undefined property';
}
```

Aquí tienes un ejemplo del comportamiento en javascript y puedes utilizar [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) para realizar validaciones.

```js
const user = {
  name: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe'
};

function getValue(value) {
  return user?.[value] || 'Error: undefined property';
}

// Retornará 'John'
console.log(getValue('name'));
// Retornará Error
console.log(getValue('middleName'));
```

Comment: Optional Chaining tambien es conocido Elvis Operator

Comment: Vaya, es primera vez que escucho de Elvis Operator, lo conocía más como Optional Chaining o bien Null Safety